# How to start Google Play Store App Details Dialog?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I use the Google ads services to show a AD,when I click the AD,the Google SDK will open a dialog with the app details,that's beautiful!

I try to get this effect, but I only find this way,that's using "market://xxxxxxxxx".This way is really to open the Play Store,but is not the Dialog.

[image]

Anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Unfortunately, that dialog is only available to Google and its select partners.

The dialog you are looking at is known as an InlineAppDetailsDialog. [Decompilation of its code reveals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734624/open-google-play-dialog-from-my-app) that it checks which application is calling it and will not display if it does not recognize the calling application's ID and signature.

To link to an application's Google Play page from another Android App, your [best bet](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#OpeningDetails) is to use a `market://` link.