# How to open app install page like Google app ads

Tags: java, android, google-play

I am developing an Android app for installing specific apps from Google Play without go to the Google Play store. And I am searching for any way to install apk file from Google Play without using Google Play store.

I am tried the Google ads intent schema that allow you to view and install app from Google Play dialog without go to play store. If you clicked on any app ad by Google you can see that dialog here is an example of used intent:

```
intent://details?id=com.iqoption&inline=true&enifd=ANRrB2M-o89kpBfnxzWr-fsTrGWfRA9qoCmNGSahSVFMz7gfeFIuU6OaFB1I0pAvDLdcm0mwAe049bUXrBqGcBxkAjX63-vj_jLa3x4_-OrZOgM_kcM_9g4Sek9BeMUBZAC93wPn-QPl3LROr5PSDP1b8gX7rUmbuLU&gref=EkQKPAoICPDf5vMFEGESLACCecsK8-ZhLtqxTT5e4Cmwbb7O9uUr5luF9hDOkLwL9ICTA38SFiFhrNkEGgItwxAC8P8HARjrwrfTAiIGGAUgATAB#Intent;scheme=market;package=com.android.vending;end;
```

But when I change the package name of the intent its does not work. It's just moved me to Google Play store.

I used this code in my button to deal with schema:

```
Intent intent = null;
                try {
                    intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                    //intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But IT DID NOT WORK and it takes me to Google Play store. Rather than opening install dialog.
Here is this the Google app ad dialog that I mean.

this the google app ad dialog:
[image: this the google app ad dialog]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Google Play Store App Details Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260896/how-to-start-google-play-store-app-details-dialog)

Comment: Thanks @Floern I changed my way to solve that problem.

Comment: @Wadelzubair how did you solve it?

Comment: I solved my problem by change my entire way and logic.

Comment: My problem is to constraint child to not go outside my app. And I have control panel for parent so I let parent install apps for their children without letting child go outside.

Comment: @Wadelzubair so basically opening the install dialog like Youtube is not possible?

Comment: @RajSuvariya Yes from my side I am not able to do it. So I changed my way.