# How to overlay Google Play app page on the top of my app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to show Google play app page on the top of my app but cannot find a way. Google play app linking page does not say anything about it. [Linking to Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play).

I have not found anything like this on Google Play Core library.
Few suggested me, it is just a custom bottom sheet.

But check the images below.

**Image 1 :** Google app on Android showing BBC app's google play page on the top of GOOGLE app.

**Image 2:** Facebook in app ad shows advertiser's Google Play page after clicking the ad.

How can I implement it ?

[image]

Comment: Its an advertisemnt by google!

Comment: The first one is a app preview and the second one is an advertisement which shows a preview of an app

Comment: No.............

Comment: Sorry. I could not get what u meant by no

Comment: I have found answer from [Android : Open google play dialog from my app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453023/7635964)